# Fluid speed field problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

I'm preparing an fluid dynamics exam and I'm trying to solve a problem where a velocity field is given: $\vec v=(2x-3y)\vec i +(3x-2y)\vec j$, and they ask me a number of things about this fluid. I have obatained most solutions, but I'm stuck in the final one. Although my question is about this last part, I'd be glad of you can "have a look" to check whether the rest of solutions are sensible. Unfortunately I could not find examples of this type of problems online, and I don't know anyone who could help me in Real World™.

First thing is to check whether this fluid is compressible. This is basically to see whether or not $\nabla\cdot v=0$. As it is the case, then the fluid is incomprehensible, and there exist a stream function such that $\vec{k}\times \nabla \psi=\vec v$.

Second is to find acceleration field $\vec a$. This is basically to apply $\vec a=\frac{d\vec v}{dt}=\frac{\partial \vec v}{\partial t}+\left(\vec v\cdot \nabla\right)\vec v=-5\vec i - 5\vec j$

Third is to find vorticity. This is $\Omega=\frac{\partial v_y}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial y}=1$. So we know this fluid "spins" counterclockwise (or it is sheared).

Fourth is to find the streamlines. This is basically to solve the set of equations:

$\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} = - v_y$

$\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y} = v_x$

This results in $\psi(x,y)=-3/2x^2 -3/2y^2+2xy +C$. Each constant C gives rise to a different streamline. **Is this correct?**

And now, where I'm stuck. They ask me to describe the shape of the streamline that crosses (1,1,0). I think this way of posing the problem is not correct, so I assume that what they really mean is to find $C$ such that $\psi(1,1)=0$. Assuming this is what they ask, $C=1$ and I get the curve $-3x^2 - 3y^2 +4xy=-2$. OK, here I'm now. **I have no idea what this curve represents**. It's not an ellipse, a parabola... the "$4xy$" terms puzzles me.

The final question is to calculate the **circulation of $\vec v$ around this curve**, which I cannot do as I do not know how to parametrise it.

PS: bonus points to anyone what points me to online resources where this kind of problems are proposed, so I can strengthen this skill. I have found nothing so far...

Comment: I would suggest that you use [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) and enter your equation $\text{-3*x^2-3*y^2+4*x*y=-2}$ to show that it is the equation of an ellipse.

Comment: I believe MIT OCW has some [nice materials](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-01-unified-engineering-i-ii-iii-iv-fall-2005-spring-2006/fluid-mechanics/) (lecture notes, psets and some solutions to chosen problems, etc.) on Fluid Mechanics that might help you.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Farcher! OK I see I have to improve my knowledge on quadratic forms. the "4xy" term represents a tilting in the ellipse. Now I have to figure out how to parameterise that... but that's a topic for another question, perhaps in a different forum.

Comment: Your interpretation of C is not correct.  There is only one (constant, arbitrary) value of C.  The streamlines are defined by constant values of $\psi$, not C.

Comment: Thanks @ChetMiller, I have been thinking and now I see your important point. Therefore I'm not sure what they mean by "the streamline that crosses (1,1,0)"...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to solve the set of coupled 1st order linear ODEs:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=2x-3y$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=3x-2y$$subject to the initial condition x = 1, y = 1, at t = 0